# React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what shown in browser's log:

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
>
> ok router
>
> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
>
> ok datawrapper
>
> invariant.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
>
> [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.

My webpack entry file `app.jsx` is:

```
import React from "react";
import Router from "react-router";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

import router from "./router/router";
import DataWrapper from './container/DataWrapper';

if (process.env.BROWSER && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  require('../../public/css/app.css');
}

let history = createBrowserHistory();
let data = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('#data').innerHTML);
ReactDOM.render(<DataWrapper data={data}><Router history = {history}>{router}</Router></DataWrapper>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

the `DataWrapper.jsx` is:

```
import React from 'react';

 class DataWrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            data: this.props.data
        };
    }

    render() {
        console.log("ok datawrapper");
        return this.props.children;
    }
}
DataWrapper.childContextTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default DataWrapper;
```

the `router.jsx` is:

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, IndexRedirect} from "react-router";

import Index from '../components/Index'

console.log("ok router");

export default(
  <Route path='/' component={Index}>

  </Route>
);
```

and the `Index.jsx` is:

```
import React from 'react';

class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("ok");
    return (
      <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
        hello world
        <div style={{display: 'none'}} id="data">{JSON.stringify(this.context.data)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

Index.propTypes = {
  location: React.PropTypes.object
};

Index.contextTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Index;
```

It seems like the warning didn't affect the server rendering. The `console.log("ok")` works in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the problem caused by the deprecated method in `react-router`.

The right way to use `Router` and `history` in `react-router 2.0` is:

```
import {Router, browserHistory} from "react-router";

...

ReactDOM.render(<DataWrapper data={data}><Router history={browserHistory}>{router}</Router></DataWrapper>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: which deprecated method did you use and replace?

Comment: @rogierschouten `createBrowserHistory()`, the method how to create `history`. You can compare the code in my question and my answer.